# RS form's captcha is not working

Tags: joomla, captcha

I'm using RS form and in a form I use captcha. But image is not showing on server. Localhost is able to show image. I have included GD library, but still image is not displaying.
Check the configuration of server:

GD Support      -   enabled 

GD Version  -       bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

GIF Read Support -  enabled

GIF Create Support- enabled

JPEG Support     -  enabled

libJPEG Version -       6b

PNG Support -       enabled

libPNG Version  -       1.2.10

WBMP Support    -       enabled

XPM Support -       enabled

libXpm Version  -       30411

XBM Support -       enabled

Comment: what is the url you use to call the captcha image?

Comment: have you tried contacting the developer?

Comment: have you created your own translation for rs form??

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling SEF and see if it works. In most cases, we have traced down the reason of the problem to be SEF.